# how to pass waypoints between source and destination lat and long in kml url for path in Google Map?

Tags: android, path, google-maps-api-3, kml

for address url :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false
```

in this url betwn source and destination we can pass waypoints
but how i can pass waypoints for kml url

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=9.036597,77.536&daddr=8.919942,77.669208&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml
```

i have tried like this

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=9.157283,77.544239&daddr=9.035239,77.784564&waypoints=9.036597,77.536|8.919942,77.669208&sensor=false&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml
```

but it is not worked so how i can pass waypoints multiple lat and long between source and destination?

Comment: This post can help you solving your problem.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745314/why-retrieving-google-directions-for-android-using-kml-data-is-not-working-anymo/11745316#11745316

Comment: @girishce26 Did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no documented way to do that.  The KML interface om maps.google.com isn't really an "API" like the Directions API with formal documentation and specs... it's just a commonly used service for simple requests.

Your best bet is to work with the JSON/XML from the directions service and transform it into KML (if you can't consume it directly).